# Attach arrows to points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am visualizing a 4 dimensional data set. 
Let's denote the variables as `x, y1, y2` and `y3`, where `x` is for dates, `y` is a continuous variable and `y2, y3` are components of 2 dimensional vectors `(y2, y3)`. Now I want to a line plot for `x` and `y1`, additionally attaching arrows for `(y2, y3)` at points `(x, y1)`.

I have tried

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y1)) + geom_line() +
      geom_segment(aes(xend=x+y2,yend=y1+y3), arrow = arrow())
```

but it doesn't work well so I think I may need to do some rescaling. How can I do this with `ggplot`?

**UPDATE**: I've attached a [sample data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsmfbmsyj8rru0p/elnino) (together with its [column definition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3xwm09nkt4s7ka/elnino.col)). The data set contains oceanographic and surface meteorological readings taken from a series of buoys positioned throughout the equatorial Pacific. The data is expected to aid in the understanding and prediction of El Nino/Southern Oscillation (ENSO) cycles (from the description of the [repository](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/el_nino/el_nino.html)). Now, for example, I want to visualize `x=day, y1=humidity, y2=zon.winds, y3=mer.winds` with the symbol described above.

**UPDATE2**: for example, I want to plot this for a particular buoy
[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having trouble figuring what you want to display.
As far as I can see, your dataset has 50 buoys that each deliver a measurement each day.

```
library(ggplot2)
elnino <- read.table('elnino.txt', col.names=c('buoy','day','latitude','longitude','zon.winds','mer.winds','humidity','air.temp','ss.temp'), as.is=TRUE, na='.')
elnino <- elnino[elnino$humidity > 40,]  # removing a single point that seems to be an outlier.

ggplot(elnino, aes(x=day,y=humidity, group=buoy)) + geom_point()
ggplot(elnino, aes(x=day,y=humidity, group=buoy)) + geom_line()
```

Which gives these two results.
[image]
[image]

What I cannot see is how do you want to display the ''zon.winds'' and ''mer.winds'' variables? I figure these in combination gives a vector, but where do you want these placed? You would get ~ 700 arrows filling your plot.

**Update**
In that case, you got it right, that you have to use geom_segment and calculate the ''x'', ''xend'', ''y'' and ''yend'', see [geom_segment](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_segment.html).

```
# We select a single buoy
el <- subset(elnino, buoy==1)

library(grid)
ggplot(el, aes(x=day,y=humidity, group=buoy)) + geom_line() + geom_segment(aes(yend=humidity+zon.winds, xend=day+mer.winds), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm")))
```

This however doe not look very nice, because the coordinates in ''zon.winds'' and ''mer.winds'' are taken as absolutes! So to utilise them, we will need to do some manual transformation of them. My values are absolute arbitrarily.

```
el <- transform(el, zon.winds = zon.winds * -0.3, mer.winds=mer.winds * -0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated my question again with an example. I think this would be more clear.